# Which NSMergePolicy do I use?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, core-data, icloud

I'm syncing a core-data app with iCloud and none of the documentation says in what circumstances you'd choose one NSMergePolicy over the other. I'm using NSMergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicy, but I sometimes get random deletions. Is there another one I should be using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ntesler,

Each merge policy has different goals. I always default to background threads using `NSMergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicy` and have the main thread use `NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicyType`. The main time the these policies matter is when you are calling `-refreshObject:mergeChanges:`. When you set `mergeChanges` to YES, then the respective truth is chosen as directed by the policy.

I've not used iCloud and hence cannot advise you on if it changes the above analysis. In my experience though, you need to choose one repository to be the "truth". Is the iCloud always the truth? I expect it should be.

Andrew

Comment: Looks like `ObjectTrumpMergePolicy` was the one I needed.

Comment: I retract the last comment. I've extensively tested all NSMergePolicies and all of them cause errors which should be easily avoided. All I need is the last writer to win, but on a property-by-property basis. Any ideas what I can do? Is there a way I could subclass NSMergePolicy and override resolveConflicts:?

Comment: ntesler, your conflict issue is between your iCloud store and the local copy? It sounds like you need to sync between the cloud and devices more often. I always perform such actions when my app enters the background or resigns its active status. IOW, be aggressive in how you push the data to the cloud. Andrew

Answer (score 0):

`NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy` is the merge policy that worked best for me. `NSMergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicy` sometimes resulted in inconsistent merging between devices, at least in memory.